# Selenium Check for text to change

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do an assert in Selenium on a page element.

Now this DOM element is refreshed on an AJAX request.
So the text inside the element changes from "Submitted for processing" to a numeric value (e.g. 500)

I want to do the assert on this numeric value. So how do I add the Selenium code for the same (i.e. change from text to numeric result)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebDriverWait and wait for element to reload and then get the content of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bucle getting the text, check if text is numeric, if not, add a delay and check again until it is numeric.

```
 while (!isNumeric(getText(textElement))) {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Java 8 version (could be converted into Java 7 with the standard Guava workarounds)--

```
Function<WebDriver,String> p = driver -> {
     WebElement e = driver.findElement(~~~~);
     String text = e.getText();
     if (text.matches("\\d+")) {
         return text;
     }
     return null;
}
String result = new FluentWait<WebDriver>().until(p);
assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(result), 9000);
```